# How to add button in React Native Flatlist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to create a very simple question-and-answer app.
If I click on the show answer button then the answer should show only where I click, but now all answers are showing when I click on the button. I fetch question answers from Firestore. What is the problem Please check my Firestore data and Flatlist code. please check the images, Thank you in advance for your support [image] [image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, View, Text, Pressable, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    import {firebase} from '../config';
    
    const Testing = ({ navigation }) =>{
      const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const todoRef = firebase.firestore().collection('dd11');
    const [showValue, setShowValue] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        todoRef.onSnapshot(
            querySnapshot => {
                const users = []
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    const {    QuestionOne, ans, optionOne, optionTwo, optionThree, optionFour
              
                    } = doc.data()
                    users.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        QuestionOne, ans, optionOne, optionTwo, optionThree, optionFour
                      
                    })
                })
                setUsers(users)
            }
        )
    }, [])
    
      return (
        <View style={{ flex:1,}}>
        <FlatList 
      data={users}
       numColumns={1}
       renderItem={({item}) => (
     
         <Pressable >
     <View>
     
       <View style={{paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10,}}>


       {item.QuestionOne && <Text>{item.QuestionOne}</Text>}

       {item.optionOne && <Text>{item.optionOne}</Text>}
       {item.optionTwo && <Text>{item.optionTwo}</Text>}
       {item.optionThree && <Text>{item.optionThree}</Text>}
       {item.optionFour && <Text>{item.optionFour}</Text>}

       {showValue? item.ans &&<Text style={{color: 'green'}} >{item.ans}</Text> : null}
       <Button title="Show Answer" onPress={() => setShowValue(!showValue)} />
      
     </View>
     
     </View>
      </Pressable>
          )} />
     </View>
     );}
export default Testing;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this, by maintaining an array of indexes, only those will be shown :)

NOte: also letmeknow if you want that func that if answer is shown and you want to hide it on press again.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, View, Text, Pressable, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    import {firebase} from '../config';
    
    const Testing = ({ navigation }) =>{
      const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const todoRef = firebase.firestore().collection('dd11');
    const [showValue, setShowValue] = useState(false);
    const [answerIndexs,setAnsIndex] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        todoRef.onSnapshot(
            querySnapshot => {
                const users = []
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    const {    QuestionOne, ans, optionOne, optionTwo, optionThree, optionFour
              
                    } = doc.data()
                    users.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        QuestionOne, ans, optionOne, optionTwo, optionThree, optionFour
                      
                    })
                })
                setUsers(users)
            }
        )
    }, [])
    
    const onPressOfShowAnswer = (index) => {
    const existingIndexs = [...answerIndexs]
    if(!existingIndexs.includes(index)){
    existingIndexs.push(index)
    }else{
existingIndexs.splice(index,1)
}
    setAnsIndex(existingIndexs)
    }
    
      return (
        <View style={{ flex:1,}}>
        <FlatList 
      data={users}
       numColumns={1}
       renderItem={({item,index}) => (
     
         <Pressable >
     <View>
     
       <View style={{paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10,}}>


       {item.Q1 && <Text>{item.QuestionOne}</Text>}

       {item.optionOne && <Text>{item.optionOne}</Text>}
       {item.optionTwo && <Text>{item.optionTwo}</Text>}
       {item.optionThree && <Text>{item.optionThree}</Text>}
       {item.optionFour && <Text>{item.optionFour}</Text>}

       { answerIndexs.includes(index) ? item.ans &&<Text style={{color: 'green'}} >{item.ans}</Text> : null}
       <Button title="Show Answer" onPress={() => onPressOfShowAnswer(index)} />
      
     </View>
     
     </View>
      </Pressable>
          )} />
     </View>
     );}
export default Testing;
```

Comment: Sir, I am getting error- 
Uncaught TypeError: setAnsIndex.includes is not a function

Comment: ahh @RahulAadam sorry, just made the edit

Comment: do check now, ive changed it

Comment: Thank you so much Gaurav sir, it's working now. 
and yes I want that func that if answer is shown and I want to hide it on press again.

Comment: @RahulAadam done, just copy the code, it should work, also do upvote if it helped you :) thanks in advance

Comment: I just added one more button for testing purposes. First button is working properly but second and third buttons are not working properly. When I click on first button then second answer hide and when I click on second button then third answer hide. second and third button working randomly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERP8K.png

Comment: You can't add another button,  please update question

Comment: I am sorry, actually, I have not added any button in my code, I have not touched anything inside your code you provided me. I just added one more docs question/answer in Firestore then automatically one more button added in my app. hope you got my point Sir.